# Why does this program terminate with "unknown signal"?

Tags: c++, crash

The following code is meant to output combinations of size 1, 2, ..., N, given an input set of size N.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>

template< typename V >
class Item
{
public:

  Item( const std::string& description,
        const V& value )
    : description_( description )
    , value_( value )
  {
  }

  std::string description() const { return description_; }

  V value() const { return value_; }

private:

  std::string description_;
  V value_;

friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& os, const Item& item )
{
  os << "{ \"" << item.description_ << "\", " << item.value_ << " }";
  return os;
}
};

template < typename T >
void addCombinationsN( const std::deque<T>& values,
                       std::deque<T>& interimResults,
                       size_t valuesStartIdx,
                       size_t n,
                       std::deque< std::deque<T> >& results )
{
  if ( valuesStartIdx >= values.size() ) { return; }
  if ( interimResults.size() >= n ) { return; }

  for ( int valuesIdx = valuesStartIdx;
        valuesIdx < values.size();
        ++valuesIdx )
  {
    interimResults.push_back( values[valuesIdx] );
    addCombinationsN( values, interimResults, valuesIdx+1, n, results );

    if ( interimResults.size() == n )
    {
      results.push_back( interimResults );
    }
    interimResults.pop_back();
  }
}

template < typename T >
std::deque< std::deque<T> > nChoose( const std::deque<T>& values )
{
  std::deque< std::deque<T> > retVal;
  std::deque<T> interimResults;

  std::cout << "adding all combinations from " << values.size() << " choices" << std::endl;

  for ( size_t n = 1; n <= values.size(); ++n )
  {
    std::cout << "# choices: " << n << std::endl;
    addCombinationsN < T > ( values, interimResults, 0, n, retVal );
  }
  std::cout << "done adding all choices" << std::endl;

  return retVal;
}

template< typename V >
class ItemDecCmp
{
public:
  bool operator()( std::deque< Item< V > >& a,
                   std::deque< Item< V > >& b ) const
  {
    return a.size() > b.size();
  }
};

template< typename V >
void populateChoices( std::deque< Item< V > >& items )
{
  for ( int i = 0; i < 28; ++i )
  {
    items.push_back( Item< V >( std::string( 1, '0' + i ), V(i) ) );
  }
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  std::deque< Item< double > > items;
  populateChoices<double>( items );

  std::deque< std::deque< Item< double > > > nChoices;
  nChoices = nChoose< Item< double > >( items );

  std::sort( nChoices.begin(), nChoices.end(), ItemDecCmp< double >() );
  std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

  for ( std::deque< std::deque< Item< double > > >::iterator i = nChoices.begin();
        i != nChoices.end();
        ++i )
  {
    for ( std::deque< Item< double > >::iterator j = i->begin();
          j != i->end();
          ++j )
    {
      std::cout << *j << " ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The code produces expected results for input (i.e. the result of calling `populateChoices()`) containers with slightly under 30 elements. However it terminates prematurely *without segfault* with input containers with more elements.

Example output with input of 3 elements:

```
$ g++ -g main.cpp && ./a.exe
adding all combinations from 3 choices
# choices: 1
# choices: 2
# choices: 3
done adding all choices
done
{ "0", 0 } { "1", 1 } { "2", 2 }
{ "0", 0 } { "1", 1 }
{ "0", 0 } { "2", 2 }
{ "1", 1 } { "2", 2 }
{ "0", 0 }
{ "1", 1 }
{ "2", 2 }
```

Example output with input of 28 elements:

```
$ g++ -g main.cpp && ./a.exe
adding all combinations from 28 choices
# choices: 1
# choices: 2
# choices: 3
# choices: 4
# choices: 5
# choices: 6
# choices: 7
# choices: 8
# choices: 9
# choices: 10
# choices: 11
```

**What I have tried** to fix the problem:

1) I suspected I may be encountering stack overflow (no pun intended) because of the recursive algorithm. However, increasing the stack size did not change the described behavior.

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 2032
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
$
$ ulimit -s 65536
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 256
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 65536
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 256
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
$
```

2) This code originally used `std::vector` instead of `std::deque`; I suspected my problem may have to do with the on-demand reallocation `std::vector` does under-the-hood. I switched the container to `std::deque` on the understanding that `push_back`s and `pop_back`s don't incur reallocation ([this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13235372/will-stl-deque-reallocate-my-elements-c), among other reading), but this also did not result in any change in runtime behavior.

3) I ran the executable through `gdb` but can't tell what its stack trace is telling me:

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /path/to/code/a.exe
[New Thread 11212.0x1884]
[New Thread 11212.0x18cc]
adding all combinations from 28 choices
# choices: 1
# choices: 2
# choices: 3
# choices: 4
# choices: 5
# choices: 6
[New Thread 11212.0x1eb4]
# choices: 7
# choices: 8
# choices: 9
# choices: 10
[New Thread 11212.0x2a5c]
[New Thread 11212.0xfa0]
# choices: 11
gdb: unknown target exception 0x20474343 at 0x7ffccb2754d8

Thread 1 "a" received signal ?, Unknown signal.
0x00007ffccb2754d8 in RaiseException () from /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffccb2754d8 in RaiseException () from /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/System32/KERNELBASE.dll
#1  0x00000003e8ddcbf1 in cyggcc_s-seh-1!_Unwind_RaiseException () from /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
#2  0x00000003e8ddccc0 in cyggcc_s-seh-1!_Unwind_Resume_or_Rethrow () from /usr/bin/cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll
#3  0x00000003d0c57fcd in cygstdc++-6!.cxa_rethrow () from /usr/bin/cygstdc++-6.dll
#4  0x0000000100402ef7 in std::_Deque_base<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > >::_M_initialize_map (this=0x6fff5d6f7a0,
    __num_elements=11) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_deque.h:707
#5  0x000000010040307a in std::_Deque_base<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > >::_Deque_base (this=0x6fff5d6f7a0, __a=...,
    __num_elements=11) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_deque.h:500
#6  0x0000000100405209 in std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > >::deque (this=0x6fff5d6f7a0, __x=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_deque.h:949
#7  0x000000010040213f in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > > >::construct<std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > >, std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > > const&> (this=0xffffcb20,
    __p=0x6fff5d6f7a0, __args#0=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:136
#8  0x0000000100404506 in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > > > >::construct<std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > >, std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > > const&> (__a=...,
    __p=0x6fff5d6f7a0, __args#0=...) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/alloc_traits.h:475
#9  0x0000000100405b04 in std::deque<std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > >, std::allocator<std::deque<Item<double>, std::allocator<Item<double> > > > >::push_back (this=0xffffcb20, __x=...)
    at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/7.3.0/include/c++/bits/stl_deque.h:1547
#10 0x0000000100401b08 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=20, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:58
#11 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=17, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#12 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=15, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#13 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=12, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#14 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=10, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#15 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=9, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#16 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=6, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#17 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=5, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#18 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=4, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#19 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=2, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#20 0x0000000100401ae1 in addCombinationsN<Item<double> > (values=..., interimResults=..., valuesStartIdx=0, n=11, results=...)
    at main.cpp:54
#21 0x0000000100401c1f in nChoose<Item<double> > (values=...) at main.cpp:75
#22 0x00000001004010d7 in main (argc=1, argv=0xffffcc20) at main.cpp:108
```

**Question**:

Can someone help identify what is causing this program to crash and why it manifests as just premature termination and not an identifiable signal, e.g. SEGV?

Secondary but related questions: why does gdb identify multiple threads being created - this is a single-threaded application. I also don't know what to make of the "unknown target exception."

**Environment**

The dev environment is cygwin on a Windows 10 64-bit Intel PC:

```
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 My-PC 2.11.2(0.329/5/3) 2018-11-08 14:34 x86_64 Cygwin
```

PS - I'm sorry to ask a "help me debug" question, but in this case because I don't know what to make of what `gdb` is telling me, I've truly hit a mental roadblock on how to identify what specifically is wrong. I asked on Meta whether this question best fit here on on another Stack Exchange site, and opinion was split between here and Code Review.

Comment: Check your memory consumption.

Comment: @user4581301 - you mean heap use? Either way, how do I do so? `top` seems unavailable in cygwin.

Comment: Read [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Consider using some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution), since Linux is very developer friendly and has [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) which will help you to find your memory corruption bug

Comment: Yes this looks like a `bad_alloc` exception and my system produces it as well. Your program uses many GB after about `# choices: 12` on my system.

Comment: Top is out of the question, but [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) should give you a hand on Windows.

Comment: @user10605163 - is `bad_alloc` exception roughly synonymous with a failure to allocate memory on the heap?

Comment: It means dynamic memory could not be allocated, yes. In this case thrown by `deque::push_back`, meaning that memory for the new element could not be allocated. You simply cannot store that much stuff in your containers. Get rid of what you don't need anymore.

Comment: `addCombinationsN` does a hell of a lot of recursive adding. For fun, place `std::cout << values.size() << ',' << interimResults.size() << ',' <<results.size() << '\n';` or similar into `addCombinationsN` after the two early exit `if`s and watch `results` head for the stratosphere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the stack trace the exception is thrown inside the call

```
results.push_back( interimResults );
```

and is most likely an exception of type `std::bad_alloc` indicating that memory for a new element for the `std::deque` could not be allocated, probably because not enough memory is available anymore.

Because `interimResults` is always `pop_back`ed from again quickly, its size will not be really big. However `results` will grow very big and will consume all of the available memory.

You simply cannot store that much data. You need to release what you don't need.

Comment: On reflection, the high memory consumption makes sense: given N choices, and the need to find all combinations of size 1, 2, ..., N, the total number of those combinations is (2^N) - 1, which is huge when talking about the input sizes of ~ 30 elements.